# Warning A non Numerical encountered Value

Tags: php

```
$totalRevenue = "";
while ($orderResult = $orderQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totalRevenue += $orderResult['paid'];
}
```

Recently updated to PHP 7.4 and start getting following error

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in on line 29

Here is what line 15 looks like

Comment: Why initialize `$totalRevenue` as string when apparently you want it to be numeric‽

Comment: I assume its a typo, but if the error message say it occurs on line 29, why are you showing us line 15?

Answer (score 0):

And in PHP 8 the warning goes to a Fatal Error.
PHP is tightening up type checking in a number of ways and places, to help stop us devs making silly mistakes.

Change the code to initialize the variable to a numeric type and it will never bother you again

```
$totalRevenue = 0;
while ($orderResult = $orderQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totalRevenue += $orderResult['paid'];
}
```